# How to make my own version of Any State in Unity Animator

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, game-engine, state-machine

In the unity animator we have the "Any State" State which is basically used for saying that for any state in that layer, we can transition to a specific state. For example, we might have an entity that can take damage, and we want to say that no matter what current state that entity is in, we always want them to transition to the damage state when they take damage.

With this in mind, "Any State" applies to all states in the that statemachine layer, is it possible to do that same thing but instead with a subset of states? If we go back to the previous example, I could say only transition to the damage state upon taking damage if we are in any of the following states : A, B, or C.

I could draw direct transitions, but is there a way to do that similar to the "Any State" functionality?

Comment: not really ... I would say simply use multiple transitions .. that's how state machines usually work. The `Any` is a very special case Unity added